# bucle for solo toma ultimo valor (python)

Tags: python, bucle-for, lambda

Alguien puede explicarme pofavor por que el siguiente código , solo se ejecuta cuando m=3  ?
y posible solucion.(python 3.6) y los checkbuttons, tambien son creados por 
                    bucle `for` antes

```
for btn, var in check_buttons:
            for m in range(4):
                if btn['text'] in lista_inversa(medio[m]):
                    var.set(1)
                    btn['bg'] = col[m]

                else:
                    var.set(0)
                    if btn['text'][0] != btn['text'][1]:  # npares
                        btn['bg'] = off_color
                    else:
                        btn['bg'] = off_colorP
```

el codigo es muy grande para ponerlo todo
`medio` es una `lista` de 4 listas y lista_inversa convierte los elementos de esas listas  en textos que pueden ser iguales al del `btn['text']` o no.

Comment: De hecho, el rango de m debería ser 0, 1, 2, 3. ¿Por qué dices que sólo se ejecuta cuando m=4?

Comment: Adicional, por favor indica la versión de Python que estás usando (`python -V`)

Comment: El `for` itera 4 veces si o si a no ser que hubiera una excepción, por lo que el código se ejecuta 4 veces por cada item de `check_buttons`.  Ahora, hay un problema de lógica, dado que las cuatro iteraciones actúan sobre el mismo botón y la variable, **el botón y su variable quedarán en el estado que lo deje la última iteración**, los demás cambios de fondo y valor no sirven de nada porque al final como mínimo el `else` del `else` de la última iteración se va a ejecutar. Por cierto,  el último valor de `m` no es 4, sino `m=3` dado que el parámetro `stop` de `range` no se incluye en el rango.

Comment: ya lo edite ,tienen razon era 3

Answer (score 0):

Miren estimados amigos:

Asi de esta manera el código funciona perfectamente

```
  for btn, var in check_buttons:
        if btn['text'] in lista_inversa(medio[0]):
            var.set(1)
            btn['bg'] = col[0]

        elif btn['text'] in lista_inversa(medio[1]):
            var.set(1)
            btn['bg'] = col[1]
        elif btn['text'] in lista_inversa(medio[2]):
            var.set(1)
            btn['bg'] = col[2]
        elif btn['text'] in lista_inversa(medio[3]):
            var.set(1)
            btn['bg'] = col[3]

        else:
            var.set(0)
            if btn['text'][0] != btn['text'][1]:  # npares
                btn['bg'] = off_color
            else:
                btn['bg'] = off_colorP
```

donde `col` es una lista de colore:

**mi intencion es reducir las lineas de codico a travez de el bucle for , como indique arriba**